# URL escaping: Is it legal to write multi-byte character "%83%4a" as "%83J" in URL?

Tags: url, escaping

Suppose an URL is encoded in a multi-byte character set where one of the characters in the multi-byte sequence could be between 0 and 127, i.e. an otherwise valid 7-bit ASCII character.

Example: The Japanese `Shift_JIS` character set, where the character `カ` would
be escaped as `%83%4a`. Now `%4a` is also the ASCII character `J`, so I could instead write `%83J`.

Would that be OK by the whatever standard(s) apply?

I'm not asking because I want to send URLs like this (although the latter saves a couple bytes), but whether I should accept those on the server side, i.e. whether it is standards-compliant and also, whether I can expect other servers to handle this in the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm basing my answer on [RFC 2396](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396), as that is what's being used by [HTTP 1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616).

According to [Section 2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396#section-2.1), there are 2 separate steps, the latter being optional:

1. URI character sequence->octet sequence
2. octet sequence->original character sequence

So the answer is: Yes, it's OK.